# TypeError: Cannot read property 'RestaurantID' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, state

How can I conditionally initialize a variable in a state?

```
this.state = {
  RestaurantID:
    typeof this.props.location.state.RestaurantID !== 'undefined'
      ? this.props.location.state.RestaurantID
      : cookie.load('cookie'),
};

 componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(BASE_URL+`/rstProfile/${this.state.RestaurantID}`)
            .then((response) => {
            //update the state with the response data
            if(response.data.length !== 0) {
                this.setState({
                    RestaurantName: response.data[0].RestaurantName,
                    Email: response.data[0].Email,
                    Zipcode: response.data[0].Zipcode, 
              });
            }
        });
```

I have a route in my application, where user profile can be visited either by someone who has link to profile or oneself. I have tried to conditionally set a variable like so, but getting the type error above.

Comment: Where is this ```RestaurantID```?  Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, i.e. the component code in question and enough calling code to gain context. Also, there is no `RestaurantID` in your code snippet. Is the error elsewhere?

Comment: My bad. Updated the code.

Comment: Are you using a constructor? or just declaring the state as a class property? I've created a small [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/typeerror-cannot-read-property-restaurantid-of-undefined-0o3f5) that works. The error you have is saying that `props.location.state` is undefined, i.e. your component isn't receiving location state. How is this value being passed to your component? Also, it is generally a react anti-pattern to store passed props into local component state, just consume them from `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way of updating the state. You should use `this.setState({ RestaurantID: typeof this.props.location.state.RestaurantID !== 'undefined' ? this.props.location.state.RestaurantID : cookie.load('cookie'),})`

Comment: Can I use setState() in constructor?

Comment: No, use it in componentDidMount() while handling the props. It may work.

Comment: console.log the values and verify that if the values are the way you want or not. if that is true, then you should have to update the states by setState. Setting the value of state in constructor is not recommended via props.

Comment: Will do. Can you please recommend how to pass the restaurantID from previous page when redirecting?

Comment: using AsyncStorage or Redux or flux.

Comment: AsyncStorage if you are using ReactNative and if you are using ReactJS, you should go with LocalStorage.

Comment: And if you are using setState, then kindly declare the state empty in constructor. Like this
```this.state = { RestaurantID : "" }```

Answer (score 0):

you should take away the assignment of the variable from the declaration of the state and do the conditional assignment on the componentDidMount. This way you prevent relying on props during the initialization as it is not recommended.

```
this.state = {
  RestaurantID: null,
};



componentDidMount() {
         console.log(this.props.location.state)
         const restaurantId = this.props.location.state.RestaurantID
        (!restaurantId) ? setState({ RestaurantID: cookie.load('cookie')}) : setState({RestaurantID: restaurantId})
        axios.get(BASE_URL+`/rstProfile/${this.state.RestaurantID}`)
            .then((response) => {
            //update the state with the response data
            if(response.data.length !== 0) {
                this.setState({
                    RestaurantName: response.data[0].RestaurantName,
                    Email: response.data[0].Email,
                    Zipcode: response.data[0].Zipcode, 
              });
            }
        });
```

also make sure that what you´re receiving through props is actually arriving, because for the kind of error that you´re receiving it seems more than a problem with the props that with the declaration of the variable. I suggested a console.log in my code so you can start debugging from there.